# why navigator.onLine() return true even if my internet connection is not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

some time i am accessing website but getting error  & `navigator.onLine()` return true
So Why i am getting return true even if i am not accessing any website.

here is my code :

```
setInterval(function(){
    if(navigator.onLine){
        return true;
    }else{
       return false;
    }
},1000);
```

this will i am testing at my office it means a large network.
there is any solution ?
          or
 i am prefer jquery ajax to check  internet connection

Comment: A philosophical concern: if your computer were connected to a huge corporate network, but couldn't reach the large network we call "the Internet", is it still "online"? Does your answer change if "huge corporate network" becomes "a home LAN"?

Comment: this will i am testing at my office.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

via [the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorOnLine.onLine):

`onLine` is true:

In Chrome and Safari if the computer is connected to any network, including a LAN, even if the LAN doesn't have a working gateway to the Internet.

In Firefox and Internet Explorer unless the browser is explicitly set to offline mode.