# Event listener for network connection change

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webrtc, navigator, stun

In JavaScript (on Chrome) I am trying to perform some task whenever a user switches from one WiFi network to another (assuming that both networks are exactly the same in terms of performance).

I started with looking at the `online` / `offline` events of the Window interface and `navigator.onLine` but it seems like that they are not triggered when we switch networks (disconnect from one network and connect to the other) because

> In Chrome and Safari, if the browser is not able to connect to a local area network (LAN) or a router, it is offline; all other conditions return true.

> you cannot assume that a true value necessarily means that the browser can access the internet. You could be getting false positives, such as in cases where the computer is running a virtualization software that has virtual ethernet adapters that are always "connected."

Ref1: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/onLine

Ref2: [why navigator.onLine() return true even if my internet connection is not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22422481/why-navigator-online-return-true-even-if-my-internet-connection-is-not-working)

Also, the `navigator.connection` object not necessarily updates to trigger `navigator.connection.onchange` event in case of switching networks.

I tried using WebRTC with STUN to capture public IP address to differentiate between the two connections but there is no event listener that would reliably tell that a network change has happened.

I understand that JavaScript can not directly access network info through the browser due to security reasons but is there an alternative that can be reliably used to trigger an event whenever the network is switched or there is no actual internet connectivity even though the computer is connected to the LAN/WiFi?

Comment: Very curious what the use-case is, if you mind sharing.

Comment: You could keep an websocket connection to your server that just responds to periodic ping or echo messages. If the websocket connection dies (and calls your `error` or `close` callback), then you have a strong hint that the network conditions changed.  Likewise, failures to connect back to the server and/or success after previously failing are other hints.

Comment: I hope there will never be a solution to this question, because when it appears, it’s going to be a privacy nightmare.

Comment: Not a complete solution, but might be helpful. If there is a connection between two peers, that means they have selected a pair of ICE candidates (local and remote). When on one of the peers' side network is changed then that peer has to gather new candidates for new network interface. I'm not sure that this continuous gathering policy can be enabled from JS, but if in your case your WebRTC session is not interrupted during network switch, then it's likely this policy is on. So, the peers will select new pair, look at event "selectedcandidatepairchange" - thus you might catch network change.

Comment: @selbie has pointed you in the right direction. Have implemented something similar previously. You won't necessarily know that the network has changed, just that the connection dropped.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for does not have wide browser support, but *does* exist in Chromium-based browsers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NetworkInformation/change_event

Comment: As I have mentioned in my question that the navigator.connection object not necessarily updates to trigger navigator.connection.onchange event in case of switching networks.

I am afraid that this solution might not be reliable.

Comment: I see. In that case you might want to share your use-case. I have some ideas depending on the constraints. You're most likely to find a server-side solution to this.

Comment: actually I have to run a network speed test whenever a new network connection is detected.

Comment: @TheBombSquad do you mean `navigator.connection.onchange` ?
Also, Will this work while you are connected to one WiFi and you click on the connect button for the other WiFi without hitting disconnect on the first WiFi (switching from one network to another)?

Comment: oof what a blunder on my part, yes I meant `navigator` :{ and NO if you click a new wifi without hitting disconnect, no event occurs.. however you can use a websocket connection and assume a network change when a 1006 occurs(and yes, if the server side goes down, it will also be a 1006, but other than *that*, it should be fairly reliable)

Answer (score 0):

This is known as "walk out of the door" problem. These slides from a 2015 IETF meeting explain it well:
https://www.ietf.org/proceedings/94/slides/slides-94-ice-6.pdf

In a nutshell what you need to do in the browser is to wait for the old connection to get disconnected and initiate an ICE restart to reestablish the connection.